# wkhtmltopdf: footer-spacing is too big when footer is changed

Tags: html, css, wkhtmltopdf

I want to hide a part of my footer in my toc, so I do the following inside the subst() function:

```
if(vars['section'] == ""){document.body.className="hide-footer-text";}
```

This works more or less: The part of my footer I want to hide, disappears successfully. But my bottom-spacing changed, see attachments. How can I set a fixed bottom spacing for my footer? (I already tried option `-B` but it didn't work)

original footer with some text and correct bottom spacing:
[image]

footer I want to use in toc (without the text above) but here the bottom spacing grows:
[image]

Additional Info: I could draw this text white instead of setting display:none, but that's no option for me (because I really need the additional space on these pages)

Edit:
Just to make sure: This is what I'm expecting on my toc-pages:
[image]
And again: I want to fill the additional space (above the line) with content, so draw the text white isn't an option.

Edit2:
Sorry for not mentioning it, but I thought it was clear: I add the footer via option `footer footer.html`

Edit3:
Thank you all for your answers, but I just found out, that if I use a footer from footer.html, then it will **always** claim the same space at the bottom of the page. So even if I place my footer at the very bottom of my page - my content won't be expanded to that point.

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: @Munchkin  at 811 rep, you should know that upvotes cost nothing. 3 people tried to help you with this question. I deleted my answer, but try and bear other peoples time and effort in mind in future.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML must be table (`<table>`).
Create rows as many as you want and then, on the last row add a css `vertical-align: bottom`.
Don't forget to set the `table` height the same as PDF paper size (without margins).

Example: If your PDF is an A4 size, then follow the next example:

```
<table class="container">
    <tr>
        <td>Header</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="bottom">Footer at bottom</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm; /* if you set -B and -T to 0 */
}

.bottom {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Example

```css
.container {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm; /* if you set -B and -T to 0 */
    border:1px solid silver;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #ddd;
    background: #fff;
}

.bottom {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

body {
    background: #ccc
}
```

```html
<table class="container">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">Paper A4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="bottom">Footer at bottom</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you want margin from bottom etc 10mm, set `-B` to 20 and `height` of `.container` set to `287mm`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this won't work because I add my footer via option `footer footer.html`

Comment: @Munchkin And why you do not want footer with tables? You can read manual http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt and use `--footer-spacing` but this way is harder I think... I dont know your current HTML and CSS so answer isnt easy `:-)`

Comment: In your answer you are showing *one* HTML for header, content & footer. But I have a separate `footer.html` which only contains my footer content. `--footer-spacing` defines the spacing between footer and content, not between footer and page-bottom.

Answer (score 1):

The best description of "sticky footer" is posted at "[Sticky Footer: Five Ways](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/)". It is not exactly the problem you are trying to solve, but may be helpful.

Another likely useful approach is to define a different footer for your TOC page. You can do this by slightly modifying the code found at [wkhtmltopdf – Add Header or Footer to only First or Last Page](http://biostall.com/wkhtmltopdf-add-header-footer-to-only-first-last-page/)

In general, the simplest and easiest way to make a footer attach to the bottom of a page is to use `position: absolute; bottom:0;` Of course, that makes it incumbent on you to keep the body from overflowing the footer.

Hope this helps.